# AAD authentication in ASP.NET Core app does not return proper header

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have an AAD authentication in my app. Unfortunatelly when user which is not logged in request any resource I get response header:

```
 WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
```

but I should get respone with header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization-uri=https://example.com
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the [`JwtBearerOptions.Challenge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.jwtbeareroptions.challenge?view=aspnetcore-1.1) property:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    // If use AddJwtBearer
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.Challenge = "Bearer authorization-uri=https://example.com";
    })
    // If use Microsoft.Identity.Web
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configureJwtBearerOptions: opt =>
    {
        opt.Challenge = "Bearer authorization-uri=https://example.com";
    })
```

Comment: Perfect solution!